# How can I combine find + insert in mongodb like oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In oracle I can:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

Is there any command in mongodb like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with the aggregation framework you can run a pipeline that uses the **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** operator as means to write the results of the query to another collection.

Consider running the following aggregate operation:

```
db.tbl_temp1.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "fld_order_id": { "$gt": 100 } } },
    { "$project": { "fld_id": "$fld_order_id" } },
    { "$out": "tbl_temp2" }
])
```

---

In the above aggregation, the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline step acts as a filter on the document stream to allow only matching documents to pass unmodified into the next pipeline stage:

```
{ "$match": { "fld_order_id": { "$gt": 100 } } },
```

and is equivalent to the SQL's `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100
```

The next **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline stage selects/reshapes each document in the stream, such as adding new fields or removing existing fields:

```
{ "$project": { "fld_id": "$fld_order_id" } },
```

is the same as

```
SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id AS fld_id
```

and the final **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** operator stage

```
{ "$out": "tbl_temp2" }
```

writes the resulting documents of the aggregation pipeline to a collection, akin to

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2
```

Comment: The `insert` from relational only inserts new records into an already existing table without any damage to other rows in the table. However, the `$out` will replace the existing collection and hence must be used with caution.